# "HTTP with Azure AD" connection is not available in my tenant

Tags: powerapp, microsoft-teams, microsoft-flow, powerapps-canvas

I was exploring on how Microsoft Teams can be provisioned using the PowerApps and Power Automate, where I came across this article [Provision Teams using Power Apps and Power Automate](https://thatapiguy.tech/2020/03/27/provision-teams-using-power-apps-and-power-automate/). In this article, they are asking to import to Power Automate - in one of the Power Automates they are using "**HTTP with Azure AD**" connection but this connection is not available in my tenant. Has anyone referred to this article and faced the same or any alternative connection for the same?

Comment: When you are saying HTTP with Azure AD is not available, what do you mean exactly? It means that it does not show up in the list of connectors?

Comment: Yes are right -  it does not show up in the list of connectors.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that [Power Platform admin setup DLP policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/create-dlp-policy) that disabled this connector in your environment.

If DLP is *not* the cause of it, then the only reason for a missing connector is likely a bug.